# Detect language from long string blocks

Tags: linux, open-source, php, language

i know this is a question that has already been asked before [( Old question on stack overflow )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php) but I've done my homeworks and share the results, and ask if there can be any other method appliable to detect a language from a string block.

First of all, I'm running a global *pseudo-crawler* that downloads web home pages, and I need to detect the language based on the text-only version of that homepage. So, text blocks are usually long ( more than 256 characters ).

Currently I'm running this pseudo-crawler on a LAMP stack.

I specify that **i know there is Google and other good APIs that can do this work**, but they're not free, and if you have to run this detection through - say - 1 billion string blocks, it quickly becomes expensive in a way that can not be considered a good approach.

Here's what I've tried to detect the language:

**1)** [Text_LanguageDetect pear package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_LanguageDetect).

**Upsides**: very quick detection algorithm. Plug'n'play on a LAMP stack.
**Downsides**: it behaves strangely on different versions of PHP. I was able to run it flawlessly on an environment with PHP 5.3, but on PHP 5.5 and PHP 7.0 it returns "english" for the 99% of the strings, even if the encoding is correct ( for arabic, chinese, and so on )

**2)** Vocabulary-driven detection ( home-made )

**Upsides**: very accurate detection.
**Downsides**: extremely slow algorithm, and you have to create a vocabulary for every language you want to detect. In my case, for every language in the world.

**3)** [NTextCat (c#)](https://ntextcat.codeplex.com/)

**Upsides**: it's the piece of code that's the youngest I've come to find on the web, it's been on active developing on 2013.
**Downsides**: you have to run it behind **mono** on debian, because it's a .net application, and this adds a negative overhead ( it's way slower on mono that running it under windows ). Plus, it detects only 14 languages instead of the sponsorized 280+, experimented on a dry run of this application through 300000 text blocks of the "real life".

Every other implementation of language detection I've come to find on the web ( java-based primarily ), uses the *"N-Gram-Based Text Categorization"*, along with the 2 ones I've mentioned above.

**So, question is: do you know any other open source project, written in any language, that can be integrated as an external module on linux that can accurately detect the language from a long string?**
Remember that, I can't use any external API ( if it's paid ), because it's slow, and the detection calls would be literally millions. I know I could write an hybrid system that caches the results of the calls for very short strings and check whether I have that detection in cache or not, but in this case "the cost" would be in terms of detection speed.

Comment: Why do you consider (2) slow? Looking up words in a table is pretty fast. Creating a vocabulary for many languages isn't a problem: word lists are easier to find than more advanced data. Is the problem agglutinative or otherwise not-exactly-word-based languages? (That's a problem I've never had to deal with.)

Comment: I didn't verified this information but time ago I were looking for some things related about language syntax lexers for an specific project with Scintilla, then I heard that notepad++ comes with keyword lists for each language they support, so maybe that could be is a starting point for (2).